# Data in useRequest function is potentially null/undefined - Typescript, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

We made a custom hook that fetches data for us. The fetching part is replaced with our generated fetch API we pass down as an argument.

```js
interface RequestModel<T> {
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
  data: T | null;
}

export default function useRequest<T>(url: string): [boolean, string | null, T | null, Dispatch<SetStateAction<RequestModel<T>>>] {

  const [data, setData] = useState<RequestModel<T>>({
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    data: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setData({
      loading: true,
      error: null,
      data: null
    });

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) =>
        setData({
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          data: json
        })
      )
      .catch((error) => {
        setData({
          loading: false,
          error: error.message,
          data: null
        });
      });
  }, [url]);

  return [data.loading, data.error, data.data, setData];
}
```

And it's usage looks like that:

```js
const [loading, error, data, setData] = useRequest<Todo>(url);
```

Now the problem that comes up when we call setData is that prevState is potentially `null` (for example the request failed and data was never set). So a call to setData like this results in an error:

```js
function handleChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      data: {
        ...prevState.data,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.title
      }
    }));
  }
```

Wrapping the setData that uses prevState in an `if (data) {}` doesn't work. I suppose it is because setState is asynchronous and data could potentially change to null (and thus it's properties to undefined) by the time setData is called.

**Question 1**
Any suggestions on how I could make this useRequest hook work? Ideally I'd like to be able to use data without having to check for null or undefined every time I use it (and it's not possible for situations like the one mentioned above).

**Question 2**
I've also thought that it might be possible to initialize data with a default state and use the default state instead of setting data to `null`. Is there a way to generate a default object based on an interface/type in Typescript? Similar to Java where variables have a default value.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-colden-t2db5?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to make it impossible to call `handleChange` if `loading === true` to avoid making multiple parallel requests (you could do it by disabling the change button for example).

Also, have you tried something like this and it didn't work?

```
function handleChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      data: prevState.data ? {
        ...prevState.data,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.title
      } : null
    }));
  }
```

About your second question, I don't think you should assign `data` to default value if error happened, because it's unclear. Using `null` in this case is better solution in my opinion.

Comment: I forgot to add the codesandbox link and added it now. I actually already made a construction where you can only call handleChange only if `!loading`. Didn't think of checking `prevState.data`. I'll have to try that and think on it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually when you check for `prevState.data` instead of trying to assign `[event.target.name]: event.target.value` in the else part it should just be `null`. Else it wont work.